# If not true (!true)

Tags: if-statement, go, go-templates

In golang's template/html package, I can use `{{ if .loggedIn }}` to check if logged in is true.

How do I check if .loggedIn is false without using ne or eq?

---

For example, I am looking for something like

```
{{ if !.loggedIn }}
<h1>Not logged in</h1>
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Use the function [`not`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions):

```
{{ if not .loggedIn }}
<h1>Not logged in</h1>
{{ end }}
```